# NFS share from Windows Server 2008 to AIX 6 client

Tags: windows, nfs, aix

Google doesn't brings up a solution for it! That's why we are asking. Maybe no one had this before?

**Q:** How can we share a directory from a Windows Server 2008 via NFS to an AIX 6 client? (the two steps/howto needed: share NFS on WinServer side AND mount the Windows NFS share on AIX6 client side)

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer the AIX side but the only real option you have on the W2K8 side is to enable the 'Services for NFS' service - have a look [HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(v=ws.10).aspx) for instruction.